# Failed to publish/generates TestNG Report in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, testng

[image]I have used Maven project with Selenium & TestNG to create automated scripts which I want to execute from Jenkins. In Jenkins I have added the TestNG plugin to publish the TestNG report. But it is not getting displayed. I'm getting the below mentioned error.

> Error: TestNG Reports Processing: START Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: /target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml Did not find any matching files. Finished: SUCCESS

[image]

Comment: and where is `testng-results.xml` actually? did you check?

Comment: Thanks : my tesnt-results.xml is placed on the following path   D:\Automation\EclipseWorkSpace\WebDriverTest1

Comment: this is when you run tests from Eclipse. Where are they when you run Jenkins? basically the problem is with your jenkins config: you need to see where results are placed, probably set `Local module directory` properly